# Canvas Blocking Page?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

So on my website I have a snowfall effect going on as it is the month of December and I wanted to celebrate, the only problem is, it blocks all of my links and stuff like that... How would I go about making the canvas not overlay my website but still work and show like on top? (You'll understand this if you visit the website.)

Website URL: http://insanewolfhd.byethost17.com/ 
Script URL: http://insanewolfhd.byethost17.com/Snowfall.js 
Where I Got The Script: http:// thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/html5-canvas-snow-effect (I'm not allowed to post more than 2 links, sorry :/)

Thank you anyone who can help, I feel like it's just a little CSS thing or something and I'm thinking wayyy too much about this :).

Comment: CSS3 has a [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) property that you can set to `none`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

Comment: Thank you @Kaiido this worked :).

Comment: Glad it helped, you could then accept the duplicate proposition ;-)